# Cargar imagen desde URL Instgram | HTML

Tags: html

Estoy intentando descargar una imagen desde el url de instagram (facebook) pero html no la detecta.

Este es el url:

https://scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/130477898_122202759624805_2855205189155619342_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=-ltQdzLz8mwAX_8yLNU&edm=AAuNW_gBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=eede2a3048dea55becdf126f5d39e58c&oe=60CC00C5&_nc_sid=498da5

**Obviamente al darle click el mismo funciona, pero al incrustarlo en mi html no.**

**En la siguiente imagen** se puede ver la seccion de instagran no tiene imagen y el texto
**profile pic** es el texto `alt` del `img`

[image: Imagen de dashboard mostrando error]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ejecutan este bloque de código podran ver a lo que me refiero.

```html
    <img src="https://scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/130477898_122202759624805_2855205189155619342_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=-ltQdzLz8mwAX_8yLNU&edm=AAuNW_gBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=eede2a3048dea55becdf126f5d39e58c&oe=60CC00C5&_nc_sid=498da5" alt="image not load"/>
```

### ¿por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Si en el navegador le das a "inspeccionar elemento", verás que la URL te devuelve **una página HTML que contiene la imagen**, no la imagen en sí.

Comment: @SJuan76 Pero, es el mismo **URL** que sale en la página de **instagram**... entonces **¿como le hace instagram para utilizar dicha imagen?**

Comment: Instagram, como muchos otros, tiene una serie de protecciones activas para evitar que otros sitios exploten sus recursos, acá estás viendo una de ellas. La URL te devolverá una imagen solamente cuando se está invocando desde el propio Instagram (probablemente la ptorección sea algo tan simple como verificar el _referer_). Si ese fuera el caso, entonces si no hay referer, devuelve un HTML donde se coloca a si misma dentro de un `<img>`, de manera que se pueda cumplir la primera condición. Si el _referer_ es una página no autorizada, probablemente cierre la conexión sin devolver nada.